# Why これは in the end of the 唆{そそ}るぜこれは！ statement?

Tags: grammar, kanji, word-order

唆{そそ}るぜこれは - is translated as "This is exhilarating" in anime. Though, various translations give "It's tempting" and google gives "I'll instigate this".

**Why is "これは" at the end instead of "これは唆{そそ}るぜ"?**

Also, why is "唆" written using "さ" on keyboard while it's read as "そそ"? It's inconvenient to write this kanji with the word discussed above in mind.

[image: 唆るぜこれは]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It’s an example of [[倒置]{とうち}](https://ja.wikipedia.org/wiki/%E5%80%92%E7%BD%AE). これは is placed at the end for emphasis.

さ is the *on’yomi* of 唆 as used in [示唆]{しさ}. The character is used in [唆]{そそのか}す because it means that.

I would say [唆]{そそ}る is a common misuse, although both my iPhone and Mac give it to me as a candidate when I type そそる. My dictionary has そそる in all hiragana. According to this [article](https://word-dictionary.jp/posts/4187#head-428ff9c8a856e9eb4eb52271278bae79), the anime you saw it in made this usage popular. No wonder it looks to me like nothing but an error.

Comment: Thanks, so it's basically "Anastrophe" and he speaks like Yoda from Star Wars, as far as I understood this.

Comment: @CandidMoon_Max_ as long as you understand that Japanese people would not think of it as strange, the way Yoda sounds strange in English. It's quite normal.

Comment: @Leebo now that makes sense, thank you! :)